# Bash: increment a variable in a while loop?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a bash script that for each file in a set, greps each line in the file for a string. Then it splits the line on commas, converts the 7th element to a float, and increments a running total by that value.

It looks like this:

```
for filename in data*.CSV; do
   echo $filename
   ACTUAL_COST=0
   grep '040302010' $filename | while read -r line ; do
       IFS=',' read -a array <<< "$line"
       ACTUAL_COST=$(echo "$ACTUAL_COST + ${array[7]}" | bc)
       echo $ACTUAL_COST
   done
   echo $ACTUAL_COST
done
```

But the problem I'm having is that this produces output like this:

```
53.4
72.2
109.1
0
```

The last value is always 0. After Googling a bit, I think this is because the `while` loop is executing in a subshell, and so the outer variable isn't changed.

I understand that I probably need to execute the inner loop in a function.

Comment: Related: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be handy to introduce another command substitution, with the core loop logic defined in a function:

```
sum_cost() {
   sum=0
   while read -r line ; do
       IFS=',' read -a array <<< "$line"
       sum=$(echo "$sum + ${array[7]}" | bc)
   done
   echo $sum
}

for filename in data*.CSV; do
   echo $filename
   ACTUAL_COST=$(grep '040302010' $filename | sum_cost)
   echo $ACTUAL_COST
done
```

Answer (score 2):

[That's not how you do shell scripting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/22565). You're running several commands in sequence for each line of the files!

Here you want something like:

```
awk -F, '/040302010/ {actual_cost += $7}
         ENDFILE {print FILENAME ":", +actual_cost; actual_cost=0}
        ' data*.CSV
```

(assuming GNU awk).

That's *one* command in total for all your files.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the subshell you can use the following:

```
while read -r line
do
    your_stuff
done < <(grep '040302010' $filename')
```

That way you are able to fill in the result(s) into the variable.